# PL/SQL ACCEPT command returns Invalid identifier?

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql

When I try to compile this simple code snippet:

```
set serveroutput on 
set verify off

accept p_job prompt 'job';

declare
  v_job emp.job%type := &p_job;
begin
  for r_emp in (select ename, job from emp where job like &p_job) loop
    dbms_output.put_line('');
  end loop;
end;
```

I get an error saying ORA00904: 'xy' invalid identifier. (xy is the text I entered in the accept)

What could be the problem? 
Ename and job are in the same table if it matters by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the substitution variable in single quotes:

```
declare
  v_job emp.job%type := '&p_job';
begin
  for r_emp in (select ename, job from emp where job like '&p_job') loop
    dbms_output.put_line('');
  end loop;
end;
```